# Jira automation: access {{issue}} variable during issue creation

Tags: jira

Is there a way to access {{issue}} variable inside a rule that creates an issue itself?

I create an automation rule that:

- is triggered by incoming webhook;
- creates new issue;
- sends web request with some data of newly created issue to another external system.

The problem is that when it comes to the last step, {{issue}} variable is not initialized with data of newly created issue, it's empty. And I need to know at least the key of newly created issue at this moment.

Is there a way to implement this in the creation rule, or I need to create additional automation triggered by creation of new issue instead?
I'd like to keep everything in a single rule if possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answering myself. I have solved this by creating another automation rule triggered by creation of a ticket by 1st rule. Later, however, I have found an information that an issue should be accessible in creation rule as {{createdIssue}} - did not check that though.